# The difference of the diameter and circumference

Tags: area

The difference of the diameter and circumference of base of a cone is $30$ cm. If the slant height of the cone is $25$cm, find the total surface area of the cone.

My attempt,
If $r$ is the radius, 
$$\frac {r}{2} - 2\pi r=30$$
$$r=\frac {-140}{27}$$.

How does it happen? $(-)$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is d = 2r.

Where d is diameter and r is radius.

So you have |2r - 2πr| = 30.

r = $|\frac{15}{1 - π}|$.

Put the value of r and slant height to solve for total surface area.

Comment: r= - 7, how? @Kanwaljit...

Comment: @Newton The circumference is always bigger than diameter, so I think you take the difference the other way

Comment: Yes Ahmed is right circumference is greater than diameter.

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla thank u.